# What is the Japanese sound word for the clinking of money?

Tags: onomatopoeia

What is the sound of coins being handed from one person to another?

Answer (score 7):

I would say 「じゃらじゃら」 is probably most common for that action, followed by 「カチャカチャ」.

(Far) less common would be 「チャリン」 for handing **multiple** coins. That would, however, be a very natural onomatopoeia choice if you are dropping just one coin onto a hard surface.

Comment: Perfect! I was trying to describe the sounds of the money-changers in the temple in Luke 19:45-48. Thanks!